# Problem with uploading multiple images in Firebase v9

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a problem with uploading multiple images in Firebase v9! It works but only with 1 image, even though I'm mapping through my array.

Everything works as I expect until the last part where it doesn't perform the uploading task for every image...
What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!
Here my code:

```
const addImagePost = () => {

  for(let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i ++) {
      const newImage = event.target.files[i]
      setSelectedFiles((prevState => [...prevState, newImage]))
  }
}

const uploadPost = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    if(loadingPost) return;

    setLoadingPost(true)

    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
            userID: user?.userUID,
            username: user?.userName,
            caption: inputPost,
            profileUser: user?.userPhoto,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp()
            
    })

    const imageRef = ref(storage, `files/${docRef.id}/image`)

      
    // It only displays the last image of the array
    selectedFiles?.map(async(file) => (
    await uploadBytes(imageRef, file, 'data_url').then(async () => {

        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef)

        await updateDoc(doc(db, 'posts', docRef.id), {

            image: downloadURL

        }, {merge: true})
      })
))
```